# Class property should be offered from another class (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using vb.net for creating web based applications. I try to create clean and easy to use code.

**My problem is:**
I am going to create a class with a property, which can has constaint values only (maybe from another class) and I want the designer to offer aceptable values.

[I want to see like in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUV9b.jpg)

example:
What should I change in the code below?

```
Public Class users 
  private _gender as byte
  public writeonly property Gender as byte
    set(value as byte)
      _gender = value
    End set
  End property
End Class

Public Class genders
    Public ReadOnly Property Female As Byte
        Get
            Return 0
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Male As Byte
        Get
            Return 1
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Enum`

```
Public Enum Genders As Byte
    Female = 0
    Male = 1
End Enum
```

Or `Const` or `Shared` properties of class if you need some other type then Integer

```
Public Class SomeTypes
    Public Const TypeOne As String = "One"
    Public Const TypeTwo As String = "Two"

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property TypeThree As String = "Three"

End Class
```

Comment: Very simple solution. I made it overcomplicated.
Thank you for the quick answer